# IPC for button click event

Tags: c#, .net, process

Ciao everyone, I would like to know how to get a message if a user clicks a button on a certain running application. I have no idea how to monitor the button click event. 
For example, I might like to monitor windows media player to see if user presses the play button before I start to fire some events. 
Would you please explain something and help me ? 
I would like to do this using IPC. Thank you.

Comment: is this on the computer or is it possibly on different computers ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use  **custom event handling** for this. You can raise event using event delegates in one class and consume that event in another class.I hope from [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9aackb16.aspx) you may get some hints

There are other links around, you may go though that and get some idea.